# Angular 4 directives are not re-evaluation

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I created a angular 4 directive in order to display parts of the views according to user's permissions.
the directives are fired when app is loaded , but they are not called after login or logout, which causing the view to stay the same altought the user permissions have been changed. will really appreicate some help.

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[accessLevel]'
})
export class AccessLevelDirective {
  private levelToPredicateMapper: {[id: string] : () => Observable<boolean>} = {};

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private readonly credantialsStorage: CredantialsStorageService,
    private readonly authentication: AuthenticationService) {

    this.createAccessLevelToPredicatesMapper();
  }
  
  @Input() set accessLevel(level: string) {
    if (level == null) {
      return;
    }

    let hasAccessLevelFunc = this.levelToPredicateMapper[level];
    if (hasAccessLevelFunc == null) {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
        return;
    }

    hasAccessLevelFunc().subscribe(hasAccessLevel => {
      this.buildOrDestroyView(hasAccessLevel);
    })
  }

  @Input() set roles(roles: [string]) {
     this.authentication.isAuthenticated()
      .subscribe(isAuthenticated => {

        let isValidArrayWithRoles = roles != null && Array.isArray(roles) && roles.length > 0;
        let isUserHasOneOfTheRoles = isAuthenticated && 
            this.credantialsStorage.get() &&
            isValidArrayWithRoles && 
            some(this.credantialsStorage.get().roles , role => roles.indexOf(role) > -1);
        this.buildOrDestroyView(isUserHasOneOfTheRoles);
      })
  }

  private buildOrDestroyView(isAuthorized: boolean) {
    if (isAuthorized) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }

  private createAccessLevelToPredicatesMapper() {
    this.levelToPredicateMapper['all'] = () => Observable.of(true);
    this.levelToPredicateMapper['guest'] = () => this.authentication.isAuthenticated().map(isAuth => !isAuth);
    this.levelToPredicateMapper['authenticated'] = () => this.authentication.isAuthenticated()
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse float-xs-none" [ngbCollapse]="menuHidden">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" *accessLevel="'guest'">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            <span translate>Login</span>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/registration" routerLinkActive="active" *accessLevel="'guest'">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            <span translate>Register</span>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            <span translate>Home</span>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
            <span translate>About</span>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/order/new" routerLinkActive="active">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
            <span translate>Create Order</span>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/orders" routerLinkActive="active" *accessLevel="'authenticated'">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
            <span translate>My Orders</span>
        </a>
        <ng-template accessLevel [roles]="['admin']">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active">
              <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
              <span translate>Admin</span>
          </a>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how your directive should "re-evaluate" after you're logged in.
Firstly, it would be better to describe `re-evaluation`.

But generally :

Unless your directive is aware of the state (logged in or not ), it's not gonna react to outside world.

There are lot's of ways to make it work :

1- Through `@Inputs` :

You can have a `@Input set state` and the state could be logged in or not and based on that you could react ( run whatever function you like`

2- Using router state :

You could inject `Router` to your directive and subscribe to it's changes and when the route is change to `/login` then you can run your function ( your re-evaluation)

3- Via a shared observable:

You could create a `Subject` and share it between your component and your directive and let the directive subscribe to and and component would fire an event and based on that run your re-evaluation.

Comment: Milad thank you for your help. I decided to user Subject as you recommended and it seems to work great. 
Is there a way to return a Subject.asObservable with predfined value (like Observable.of)?  if so , I can return Subject.asObservable() from authentication.isAuthenticated.

Comment: You can't do that, but you instead can use BehaviorSubject which accepts an initial value